# Rails 3 Symbol.gte method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, activerecord

I saw the following code example:

```
Subscription.where(:created_at.gte => t0)`
```

To me, this seems a little more ruby/rails-like as opposed to:

```
Subscription.where("created_at > ?", t0)`
```

However, attempting to reproduce this in my own code on results in:

> undefined method `gte' for :created_at:Symbol

I'm not certain, but I believe this is a MongoDB method. If so is there any way I can extend ActiveRecord to make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. This is [mongoid query DSL](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries).

Similar way to extend `ActiveRecord` is achieved using [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem. However, it is slightly different.

```
Subscription.where{ created_at.gte => t0 }
```

Notice different brackets and `created_at` is not a symbol.